# Name of short story written (I believe) in the 1950's about a man who builds a listening device that can hear the scream of rose flowers when cut

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was in a collection of short stories in an Alfred Hitchcock anthology I believe.  In the story, the guy uses this listening device that can hear things below and above human hearing (he can hear the flowers being cut by a neighbor because they scream).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

Roald Dahl's [The Sound Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009A2UM66)

It was part of an anthology he wrote called "Someone Like You" which he published in 1953.

I remembered it as an episode of the 80s TV series "Tales of the Unexpected" which used a lot of his short stories.

People familiar with Dahl's kids books tend to be surprised that he also wrote of adult fiction, including horror.

Comment: You certainly don't want to leave "My Uncle Oswald" on the bookshelf next to "Willy Wonka" and "James and the Giant Peach"...

Comment: Let alone *Switch Bitch*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots huh?... Oh, that's a book title